# Web-service in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

newbie to webservice concept!
I did find a ISBN webservice online and am trying to figure out how to call that service in php and what response i will get back. When i looked at it's wsdl file, i couldn't understand as it had a lot of confusing tags in it.

Question is, how do i figure out the (methods & parameters to those methods) provided by the webservice by just looking at it's wsdl file. Here is the link http://www.webservicex.net/isbn.asmx to the service.

Any example request to this service would be a great start for me to understand things better on making webservice calls by just looking at it's wsdl file.

Comment: If you have an example of a working ISBN I can help you, do you have one? You can test at http://www.webservicex.net/isbn.asmx?op=GetISBNInformation

Comment: I do not have one... by the way, could you walk me through the link in your comment. what is the purpose of it webservicex.net/isbn.asmx?op=GetISBNInformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to see methods of Soap WebService is:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/isbn.asmx?wsdl');
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

Comment: the above code helped :)